# What does the commands after docker image mean

Tags: docker

consider this docker command:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -v ~/.htaccess:/data/.htaccess pypiserver/pypiserver:latest -P .htaccess packages
```

After the image there is this command `-P .htaccess packages`. What does this command do? Is it to run additional commands after the docker image runs? I couldnt find any documentation on this.

I took this docker command from this [page](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments after the image name are passed to the container as arguments to the image's entry point.  In the case of `pypiserver/pypiserver`, [the entry point](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver/blob/master/Dockerfile#L24) is `pypi-server -p 8080`, and the `-P .htaccess package` is added on to that, so the full command run inside the Docker container is `pypi-server -p 8080 -P .htaccess package`.

See also: [the section in the `docker run` reference on overriding `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options)